# firefox --headless selenium возвращает ошибку ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Запускаю тесты на двух браузерах: Chrome и Firefox.
На Chrome --headless работает корректно.

Firefox --headless возвращает ошибку. Причем без --headless все работает отлично:

```
def get_firefox_options():
    options = firefox_options()
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    return options
```

Пробовала устанавливать размер окна, но ошибка оставалась:

```
def get_firefox_options():
    options = firefox_options()
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    return options
```

Ошибка:

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0000023EFA58C550>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"element click intercepted","message":"Element <div class=\\"card mt-4 top...sys.mjs:208:29\\nreceiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:97:31\\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an
        error.
    
        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.
    
        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get("status", None)
        if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get("value", None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
                import json
    
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value) == 1:
                        value = value["value"]
                    status = value.get("error", None)
                    if not status:
                        status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                        message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                        if not isinstance(message, str):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get("message")
                    else:
                        message = value.get("message", None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    
        exception_class: Type[WebDriverException]
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_SHADOW_ROOT:
            exception_class = NoSuchShadowRootException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif (
            status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER
        ):
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
            exception_class = JavascriptException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
            exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
            exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
            exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
            exception_class = ScreenshotException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
            exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
            exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
            exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
            exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
            exception_class = UnknownMethodException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if not value:
            value = response["value"]
        if isinstance(value, str):
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and "message" in value:
            message = value["message"]
    
        screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
        if "screen" in value:
            screen = value["screen"]
    
        stacktrace = None
        st_value = value.get("stackTrace") or value.get("stacktrace")
        if st_value:
            if isinstance(st_value, str):
                stacktrace = st_value.split("\n")
            else:
                stacktrace = []
                try:
                    for frame in st_value:
                        line = frame.get("lineNumber", "")
                        file = frame.get("fileName", "<anonymous>")
                        if line:
                            file = f"{file}:{line}"
                        meth = frame.get("methodName", "<anonymous>")
                        if "className" in frame:
                            meth = f"{frame['className']}.{meth}"
                        msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                        msg = msg % (meth, file)
                        stacktrace.append(msg)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
        if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if "data" in value:
                alert_text = value["data"].get("text")
            elif "alert" in value:
                alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="card mt-4 top-card"> is not clickable at point (120,499) because another element <footer> obscures it
E       Stacktrace:
E       RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
E       WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
E       ElementClickInterceptedError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:279:5
E       webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:160:11
E       interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:119:11
E       clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:208:29
E       receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:97:31

..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:245: ElementClickInterceptedException
```

**UPD:** эта ошибка воспроизводится только на сайте https://demoqa.com/. Попробовала запустить firefox на тестах для другого сайта - все прошло хорошо.

Comment: Firefox --headless использует другую графическую систему, чем обычный Firefox, и страница может отображаться не так, как ожидалось.
Попробуйте добавить задержку перед кликом на элемент

Comment: я использую expected_conditions для ожидания кликабельности элемента - это не подходит? нужно поставить что-то типа implicitly_wait?

Comment: Попробуйте сначала получить и посмотреть содержание страницы в целом, с помощью driver.page_source, если страница будет пустая, то уже можно отталкиваться и искать решение от этого

Comment: @Graptos попробовала метод, выполнен успешно. Но тесты также падают

Comment: А содержание страницы проверили, что получается? Там есть искомый элемент? @Natl